# Nginx only works when setting worker-process user to root

Tags: nginx, permissions, centos, http-status-code-404, worker-process

When setting nginx worker-process user to different than `root` on CentOS7 it returns 404 not found.

working with  `user root;` in nginx.conf

```
root      3776  0.0  0.1  46580  1056 ?        Ss   15:28   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
root      3777  0.0  0.3  47008  3540 ?        S    15:28   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

not working with  `user nginx;` in nginx.conf

```
root      3837  0.0  0.1  46580  1056 ?        Ss   15:35   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx     3838  0.0  0.3  47008  3540 ?        S    15:35   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

On `error.log`

```
2019/06/07 15:35:06 [crit] 3838#3838: *1 stat() "/mnt/projects/samir" failed (13: Permission denied), client: [removed], server: [removed], request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "[removed]"
```

What permissions I need to add ? I tested changing group of folder to nginx:nginx, adding 777 permission, 755 tested also.

Comment: You need to give access to `/mnt/projects/samir` to the nginx user. Also make sure it has read access to the parent directories, else just giving access to `samir` folder may not work

Comment: Okey. It works. But there is one problem. Why every folder need to have ownership of nginx:nginx ? Different users have different folders and every user has its ownership on folders.

Comment: Now it gives ````Permission denied```` when that user logs in. Because actually user don't have any ownership on any folder in system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

`chmod +x -R /mnt/projects`